# multiple conditionals in shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script

This is driving me insane. There are many posts on this but nothing is working for me. I want to check if a file is not an avi or mpg then I want to exit. Here is a simple example:

```
#!/bin/sh

extension="avi"
if [ $extension != "avi" ] || [ $extension != "mpg" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: File is not an avi or mpg"
        exit 1
fi
echo "I should print out"
```

This always returns the ERROR message which it shouldn't. I've also tried:

```
if [[ $extension != "avi" ]] || [[ $extension != "mpg" ]]; then
if ([[ $extension != "avi" ]] || [[ $extension != "mpg" ]]); then
if [ $extension != "avi" -o $extension != "mpg" ]; then
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake in your logic. Both conditions have to be filled not just one so you need the AND (&&) operator instead of the OR (||). Try:

```
if [ $extension != "avi" ] && [ $extension != "mpg" ]; then
```

or more elegant:

```
if [ $extension != "avi" -a $extension != "mpg" ]; then
```

Comment: Correct, but not optimal. I edited the answer for a single `test`.

Comment: @RichHomolka I edited the post again to show both solutions. Although your solution is more elegant, I feel that mine answers the question better by showing what was wrong with the initial statement. And the explanation with the && operator makes more sense with my example.

Answer (score 2):

[`case` statements](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-82) are designed for precisely this sort of situation. With the example given, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

extension="avi"
case "$extension" in
  avi | mpg )
    echo "I should print out"
    ;;
  * )
    echo "ERROR: File is not an avi or mpg"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

This has the obvious advantages of being more easy both to expand and to read.

Comment: `case` is indeed the better solution for this instead of an `if`.